# What is the antonyms of "come closer"?

Tags: antonyms

What is the antonyms of "come closer"?

Example two person sitting on a bench.

One of the person sit to close to another.

Another person say "xxx"?

Comment: Is there an emotional relationship between them? Or just friends? There are expressions more suitable when one is fired up, rather than just too close.

Comment: Daddy and son @user3169

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say "move away", but asking someone to move away is unfriendly, so this means that it needs to be handled social. People don't just say "move away" unless the social context is just right. Instead they might say

> Oh, we're a bit bunched up here aren't we, let's make a bit of space for ourselves, shall we.

or

> Dad, why're you sitting here?

or

> I'm sorry, could I ask you move over a little, sorry, thanks.

or

> Just go away will you. I've told you I'm not interested.